# Android Studio Design not correct

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a weird issue where my design does not render correctly in my emulator? I have tried editting activity_main.xml and it only lets me place items in specific areas and no free move. content_main.xml allows me to free move items but they render completely different.

I am new to Android Studio and want to spend time learning it but I have met this hurdle.

Here is an example of what it looks like...

(Left - Android Studio, Right - Emulator)
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDF8p.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nathankent.design2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="Sign In"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I think both,  Android Studio and Xamarin Android, dont have that realistic layout preview. Also, my tip for you is to use your Android smartphone instead emulator for simple layout look test.

Comment: Add your design XML so it will easy to give suggestions

Comment: I'd suggest editing the XML manually, rather than relying exclusively on the visual editor. Also, because of the multiple different screen densities and sizes Android needs to support, there's no guarantee that what you see in the design pane is exactly what you will see on an emulator or device.

Comment: @PeMaCN my Android phone is in for repair right now, Emulator is the best I can do :(

Comment: @VinayagaSundar I've updated with XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your questions i can understand you're using new Android studio. So maybe it using constraints layout make sure you're giving constraints for both horizontal and vertical. Otherwise it'll display like this [Constraints layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: It looks like I have, I have the hang of it now I think. You place where you want the item then set anchor points on the X,Y and it can move freely on those? It seems to be displaying correctly now.